# Add to associative array -- but no duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

My goal is to append a new set of product records to an existing associative array, but ensure each product is represented only once.  I wrote the function below.  It looks like way too much code for something this simple.  Is there a PHP array function I need to learn about?

```
function _append ( &$already, $addition ) {
    while( $result = mysql_fetch_array( $addition ) ) {
        $already_found = FALSE;
        foreach ( $already as $try ) {
            if ( $try["products_id"] == $result["products_id"] ) {
                $already_found = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !$already_found ) { $already[] = $result; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the product ID as the key, like `$already[$result['products_id']] = $result;`, and then you can use `array_key_exists` to check the product ID easily against all the existing products.  (Or, don't.  Either way, you'll only have one product per ID; if you don't check, the latest duplicate will overwrite earlier ones.)

Either way, you get rid of the `foreach` altogether.

```
function _append(&$already, $addition) {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($addition)) {
        if (!array_key_exists($result['products_id'], $already)) {
            $already[$result['products_id']] = $result;
        }
    }
}
```

The catch is, your array is no longer numerically indexed.  Wherever you add items to it, you add them with their key (the value of products_id).  But you can say `foreach ($items as $item)` just like always.

Comment: I'm using an associative array, so $item['product_id'] is not a key.  I'm not sure how to apply your answer.

Comment: You're using an associative array for each item, but `$already` is apparently numerically indexed.  And as i understand it, the `products_id` field *is* the key; your entire definition of "duplicate" is that the two match.  If you change things so that you're using the item's products_id as the key....eh.  Lemme edit.

Answer (score 1):

How about assigning the product id as the array key in `$already`?

```
while( $result = mysql_fetch_array( $addition ) ) {
  $already[$result['products_id']] = $result;
}
```

This will of course overwrite the old product record, but it should gracefully avoid duplicates!

Comment: So change it to a multidimensional array, right?  I could do that, but my current solution does work and the associative array is awfully convenient.

Comment: All you're doing is switching from PHP-defined keys to ones you specify yourself. @cHao explains it nicely above.

Comment: Thanks, I see your answer agrees.  I did need the extra explanation, though!  And I also needed the feature to not overwrite the exisiting record.